# Cannot login to Windows 10 with domain or local user after Windows update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, login

Today, two of my machines have received Windows updates and rebooted. After rebooting, the login screen showed both my username as well as an inputbox for username and password, which struck me as odd (usually it's only password if the username is displayed).

I tried to log in with the usually logged in domain user, but I could not log in. I tried my own (domain administrator) account, which could not log in either. Finally, I tried the local administrator account (yes I specified .\administrator), but that was rejected as well.

All attempts to log in give me the same error as follows (translated from Dutch):
"This password is incorrect. Please check if you are using the password of your Microsoft-account. U can always reset it on account.live.com/password".

ALL user accounts are able to log in to other machines. None of these accounts are Microsoft accounts, they are either active directory accounts (users and my own) or local accounts (local administrator).

How can I fix this (keeping into account that I am not able to log in to the machine)?

All Windows versions concerned are Windows 10 1809.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to talk to your Company Admin. They can verify / reset the domain user name and password.  They can log into your machine and reset the local admin password.

Comment: @John I (or better we) are the Company Admin. None of our accounts can access these machines anymore - not the local users, not the domain users. I myself am a domain administrator, and I get the exact same error message.

Comment: That seems strange . You can normally log into any machine on your domain with a domain account.  Take one machine and do a Windows 10 Repair Install (Media Creation Link) and update Windows to V2004.

Comment: @John Upgrading to 2004 is not an option, as 1809 is the highest possible version for us to get vendor support for all the hospital related software on the machines.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that this is related to KB4576754, the rolling out of the new Edge. After installing this KB, the issues started popping up.
Reading about the update states that it cannot be rolled back - I uninstalled the new Edge, and the issue remains...

Comment: Additional info: as described in the answer to Rajendra Rathore, I can boot into safe mode and change my password as admin but to no avail.
I've tried removing the PC from the domain or adding it to another domain, but every popup that involves security only gives me the "no" option (as in: there literaly is no "yes" button in the popups).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen before. Somehow after the update it now wants you to sign in with a live account, not a domain account.

In my case it was so bad that the username was incorrect and could not be changed even.

I had to hack into the system by using a windows setup boot stick, run setup, press shift-f10 to access a command prompt and use "tricks" to create a local username other than administrator (as that use is disabled by default) and make that user administrator.

Once done, I was able to restore things again.

Comment: I'll try to add a new local administrator account, but I fear that the result will be the same (Windows will just insist that it is a live account). I'll update with the results. Thanks though!

Comment: I had the same, once you have the local account, you can switch to it. It just doesn't work with the username Administrator. Its a special user

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to Rajendra Rathore, creating a new local user doesn't change anything. I created a new user, but still cannot log in with the new local user. The exact same message is given when not in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following steps: -

1. Boot your system with 3rd party application software, that can enable & reset your local administrator password, I used Hiren boot.
2. Enable your local administrator account and reset it's password.
3. Restart your machine and login with local administrator credentials.
4. look at your services.msc and change startup type & status as per windows requirements.

Thanks,

Comment: I know my local administrator password. In fact, when I boot to safe mode, I can log in and change my password. As soon as I reboot the PC however, and try to log in as .\Administrator, Windows insists that this is a Microsoft account and gives me the same message as in my initial post.
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: As I guessed, the newly created local account cannot log in as well. I've tried to log in with .\NewAccount and the new password, and I get the exact same message (This password is incorrect. Please check if you are using the password of your Microsoft-account. U can always reset it on account.live.com/password). Somehow Windows thinks ALL accounts are Live accounts...

Comment: Please have a look at services.msc,

Comment: What should I look for specifically please? You mentioned startup type & status, startup type of what exactly?